# how to access first column of matrix3f in point cloud library?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

The code below calculates the eigenvectors and stores in a matrix, How do I access the first column, first element?.

```
    Eigen::Matrix3f eigen_vectors;
    pcl::eigen33 (covariance_matrix, eigen_vectors, eigen_values);
    std::cout << "eigenvector:"<<eigen_vectors<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first column and element:

```
std::cout << "first element: " << eigen_vectors(0,0) << std::endl;
```

To get the first column:

```
std::cout << "first column: " << eigen_vectors.col(0) << std::endl;
```

A quick overview of such functions can be found at:
[Quick Reference Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html)